# Extracting Specific Values to TXT from PDF using a Javascript Sequence

Tags: javascript, ocr, acrobat, pdf.js

I can not find a proper javascript solution for creating a sequence in Adobe Acrobat that will extract text into a .txt file; based on certain criteria.

I have over 500 pdfs with images & financial data on them. I need to extract specific values from these pages. Including values such as: Check number, check date, check amount.

I tried the example at:
https://www.evermap.com/javascript.asp#Title:%20Extract%20ISBN%20numbers

I even created a PDF with ISBN numbers and it doesn't work.

In my PDF I have the below data:

ProcDate: 2019/01/04

AccountNum: 69447885236

CheckAmt: 157.52

SerialNum: 8574

MflmSeqNum: 268245062738

ProcDate: 2019/01/14

AccountNum: 69447885236

CheckAmt: 2,415.36

SerialNum: 8570

MflmSeqNum: 268545187745

I need to extract the values into a text file (or excel table) in a delimited format. The expected output is below:

2019/01/14; 2,415.36; 8570

2019/01/04; 157.52; 8574

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with a little tweaking and getting the loops to carry down I was able to get the desired output the only problem is that it was repeating data and they did not remain correlated:

Below is the loop info:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i++)
    {
        numWords = this.getPageNumWords(i);
        var PageText = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < numWords; j++) {
            var word = this.getPageNthWord(i,j,false);
            PageText += word;
            }

        var strMatches = PageText.match(reMatch);
        if (strMatches == null) continue;

    for (var o = 0; o < this.numPages; o++)
    {
        numWordsAmt = this.getPageNumWords(o);
        var PageTextAmt = "";
        for (var k = 0; k < numWordsAmt; k++) {
            var wordAmt = this.getPageNthWord(o,k,false);
            PageTextAmt += wordAmt;
            }

        var strMatchesAmt = PageTextAmt.match(reMatchAmt);
        if (strMatches == null) continue;

    for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)
    {
        numWordsNum = this.getPageNumWords(p);
        var PageTextNum = "";
        for (var l = 0; l < numWordsNum; l++) {
            var wordNum = this.getPageNthWord(p,l,false);
            PageTextNum += wordNum;
            }

        var strMatchesNum = PageTextNum.match(reMatchNum);
        if (strMatchesAmt == null) continue;

        // now output matches into report document
        for (j = 0; j < strMatches.length; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < strMatchesAmt.length; k++) {
                    for (l = 0; l < strMatchesNum.length; l++) {
            Out[strMatches[j].replace("ProcDate: ", "")+" , "+strMatchesAmt[k].replace("CheckAmt: ", "")+" , "+strMatchesNum[l].replace("SerialNum: ", "")] = true; // store email as a property name
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```